# Aggregating two values in a panel data with the same date and id but different type

Tags: python, r, aggregate

I have been trying to work on this dataset that includes quantities for two types of sales (0,1) for different counties across different dates. Some dates, however, include both type 1 and type 0 sales. How can I merge type 1 and 0 sales for the same date and same id? The dataset has over 40k rows and I have no idea where to start. I was thinking about creating an if loop but I have no idea how to write it. It can be in python or R.

Essentially, I have a table that looks like this:

| Date | City | Type | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | Rio | 1 | 10 |
| 2020-01-01 | Rio | 0 | 16 |
| 2020-03-01 | Rio | 0 | 23 |
| 2020-03-01 | Rio | 1 | 27 |
| 2020-05-01 | Rio | 1 | 29 |
| 2020-08-01 | Rio | 0 | 36 |
| 2020-01-01 | Sao Paulo | 0 | 50 |
| 2020-01-01 | Sao Paulo | 1 | 62 |
| 2020-03-01 | Sao Paulo | 0 | 30 |
| 2020-04-01 | Sao Paulo | 1 | 32 |
| 2020-05-01 | Sao Paulo | 0 | 65 |
| 2020-05-01 | Sao Paulo | 1 | 155 |

I want to combine, for example, Rio's quantities for both type 1 and 0 on 2020-01-01, as well as 2020-03-01, and the same thing for Sao Paulo and all subsequent counties. I want to aggregate types 1 and 0 quantities but still preserve the date and city columns.

Comment: You should consider reading data as pandas dataframe and then you should make aggregating on columns without type of sales

Comment: You could pivot the table so that there is a column for type 0 sales and a column for type 1 sales. You could try `pivot_wider` from the tidyr package in R to do this. It's difficult to give you a worked example since we don't have a sample of your data (an image is not helpful since it can't be copy-pasted to test and verify results, and we don't know any of your variable names)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('your_file_name.csv')
df.pivot_table(values='Sales', index=['Date', 'City'], aggfunc='sum')
```

Comment: Will this still preserve the city? There are multiple cities that have the same date. I tried editing the question to give a better idea of the dataframe

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pandas `groupby` and `agg` functions to do this operation. Here is some example code:

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['3/10/2000', '3/11/2000', '3/12/2000', '3/10/2000'],
                    'id':[0,1,0,0], 'sale_type':[0,0,0,1], 'amount': [2, 3, 4, 2]})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.groupby(['date', 'id']).agg({'amount':sum})
>>> amount
date       id        
2000-03-10 0        4
2000-03-11 1        3
2000-03-12 0        4
```

Comment: This seems like I am creating a new data frame with dates and amounts. How can I automate this process so that it runs on the 40k rows I have?

Comment: read it as dataframe from the file you have

Comment: My solution is just an example. Since I don't have your CSV file, I created my own sample data to demonstrate the concept.

Answer (score 0):

My version of code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pandas as pd

# generating a sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame([['10-01-2020', 311100, 'ABADIA', 'MG', 'MINAS', 'IVERMECTIONA', 0, 68],
                  ['10-01-2020', 311100, 'ABADIA', 'MG', 'MINAS', 'IVERMECTIONA', 1, 120]],
                  columns=['date', 'code1', 'code2', 'code3', 'code4', 'code5', 'type_of_sales', 'count_sales'])

# printing content of dataframe
print(df)

# using group by operation over columns we want to see in resultset and aggregating additive columns
df = df.groupby(['date', 'code1', 'code2', 'code3', 'code4', 'code5']).agg({'count_sales': ['sum']})

# aligning levels of column headers
df = df.droplevel(axis=1, level=0).reset_index()

# renaming column name to previous after aggregating
df = df.rename(columns={'sum':'count_sales'})

print(df)
```